# Ubuntu sound not working after sleep/suspend

Tags: ubuntu, audio, alsa

Whenever I sleep my laptop I mean if I down the flap sound doesn't work, every time i have to restart my laptop for sound to make working.

Fo instance right now sound is not working(since I closed the flap few minutes back.) so I check sound app and in output tab its showing

```
Speakers 
Built-in Audio
```

but still I can't hear the output sound.

I've even tried `sudo alsa force-reload` but still same problem.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem on mint17

Comment: Can you post the output of ```aplay -l``` from when it happens here? Sounds like the audio device is not properly reactivated after sleep.

Comment: Many question and answer about this topic on our sister-sites. You can start a search e.g. from ["no sound after suspend/resume"](https://askubuntu.com/q/190146/196535) or from ["Ubuntu 16.04 changes sound device after suspend, how to fix?"](https://askubuntu.com/q/762816/196535) on askubuntu...

Answer (score 1):

I just installed `pavucontrol` and things started working.  Checkout this [qa](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=184577)